# AnyLogic - Resource Pool Stored as Multiple Locations

Tags: anylogic

I am using AnyLogic to model a process where an Agent needs to retrieve a resource that could be at 1 of several locations. I am having difficulty "storing" resources at multiple locations. I have "moved" the resource to one of two locations using `moveTo()`, but when the Agent goes to the other location - where the resource is NOT stored, it still seized the resource. Is there a way to limit the seize to only look for resources at that location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In 8.3.1, your resource selection can be "Nearest the agent".

In previous versions, you can select "Customize resource choice" to select a specific agent.  This might look something like agent.location == unit.location, where agent is the agent doing the seizing and unit represents a unit of the pool.  If the resource agent and seizing agent both have a location variable that matches, the seize will seize that agent.